# Guitar Amplifier Peavey Backstage Plus

Tags: amplifier, darlington

The fuse of this guitar amplifier blows.

Changing the output transistors had the amp working for a while, but then after a while the fuse blew again.

The output transistors that were changed are new.  The configuration based on the schematic here seems to be a Darlington style push pull B class amp output (correct me if that is wrong) and that all seems to be okay.

From what I understand this problem with the fuse blowing could also be the zener diodes, is that correct?  If so while I am at it, is it recommended to change the filter capacitors as well?

One other thing. For draining the filter capacitors, is the cement type 2k ohm, 10 watt resistor on the terminals necessary, or is that needed for only tube guitar amplifiers?

[image]

Comment: *Note* : This is the output part of the schematic of The Peavey Backstage Plus Guitar Amplifier, not the entire schematic.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. That is a typical class AB amplifier. When the transistors were replaced maybe they were not a matched pair or the CR15 temperature sensor is not close to them like it should be.

Comment: Okay, that is class AB...but that is a Darlington push pull, correct? (emitters to base, collectors connected).  Thanks I will double-check transistor specs.  That does seem to be okay though in that regard.

Comment: Thank you.  And it is pushing and pulling as well correct? (+ sine wave one set of transistors, then - sine wave the other pair of transistors)Is the CR15 working to prven

Comment: Thank you.  I will check the CR15.  Is the CR15 working to prevent crossover as well or is the main function just based on temperature and heatsink connection?  Thanks again for your input.

Comment: I cannot seee how that circuit will ever work. Where is the push/pull output (it seems to connect to ground). How does it connect to the speaker (I see no connection). Maybe I'm having a bad day?

Comment: @Andyaka the amplifier does appear to be inside out ... GND appears to be the output voltage, but the speaker return is taken to 0V on the transformer secondary. Now, conventionally, 0V and GND are the same thing ... but not here bwahaha! Leaving the question ... why?

Comment: It is interesting...it seems that all emitters are hooked to ground.

Comment: @Andyaka The power amp output stage essentially runs off its own floating power supply and the output stage essentally pulls at its power rails to shift the center tap around which serves as one speaker connection, the other being the actual 0V line.  That topology keeps most of the power amp at comparatively fixed voltage levels instead of having it travel around with the speaker voltage, obviating the need for charging and discharging stray capacitances across large voltage distances.

Comment: I think the 0V marking indicates that 0V DC is expected there, not that it is a 0V node. However I still don't find a connection from the push pull output to the speaker ... ok, I see - the power amp is basically pulling the power supply, and thus the transformer centre tap, around chassis 0V.

Comment: @user107063 OK so the idea is keeping the power amp internal nodes near to chassis potential, presumably this makes it a bit easier to keep things stable. This makes sense. Stability of guitar amps with a lot of gain can be tricky because of the very high input impedance needed (I ran into this in the past).

Comment: @danmcb It's not about keeping things more stable.  This way only the power transistors get to see ±35V or similar while the driver stage can stay within ±15V, the level that opamps and much other small-signal stuff is comfortable with.  Moving the whole power rail distance against the inertia of stray capacitances would impact the slew rate quite more in the driver stage than right at the output.  The main disadvantage is that it looks crazy.

Comment: hmmm, I don't understand how this is solving that problem (which I didn't even know exists, or why it does ...) Basically we are just tying chassis to a different point in the circuit. The low voltage part of the amp should never see anything outside its own rails either way.

Comment: @danmcb The standard topology has the same ground for the power rails and the signal ground.  So the output transistors travel a huge distance from signal ground, and the driver transistors need to travel just as far (actually a bit further).  But that means that the opamp feeding the driver transistors would require an output swing as large as the power rails, too.  Instead, Peavey essentially uses the power rail sieve capacitors as bootstrap capacitors for generating a larger voltage swing than the driver stage has.

Answer (score 0):

## Background (1st look)

This design uses a standard Class AB design with fixed gain controlled by an inverted output using the drivers as the floating ground symbol and inverted output as the capacitance divider from the power bridge diodes.

Most often it is the other way around but it doesn’t matter here since negative feedback uses the Op Amp +ve input with AC gain=R60/R61=~7

CR15 must be heatsunk to output drivers and are designed to run with temp compensation so the diode pair DC voltage is reduced by -2.1mV/‘C from 1.34V for the PNP’s and the NPN’s reduce the bias with a Factory Picked (F.P.) 22 Ohm R45 to match roughly leaving a 0.19V idle DC OpAmp to reduce crossover distortion and Quiescent current.

## Problem

- blows 2A fuse after a few minutes

  - due to power On cap surge current , fuse should be slow blow
- check all Vdc on schematic as it warms up and  any F.P. Resistors may need adjustment. (Report errors in DC
- check/ replace caps with same or bigger low ESR caps as under power load with loud bass unequal rectification from faster decay time creates more DC offset and load current with distortion.
- feel which parts are too hot to touch.

## 2nd look

Both Polarity drivers have active current limiting starting around 4A or 32V into 8 Ohms but speakers are usually <4 Ohms DC so any speaker differences or DC offset from bad caps or bridge diodes may trigger current limiting but 4~5A secondary shud be <~2A primary for a fuse. But again it must be slow blow.  Transformer would be expected to be about 4.4:1 (est) turns ratio .  (120*1.4/39=4.4) So it is protected.

Comment: Thank you Tony.  I will study this, and check everything.  What about the draining of filter capacitors?  Is the cement type 2k ohm, 10 watt resistor fine for that or is that only necessary for draining caps on tube guitar amplifiers?

Comment: Draining not needed since <50V is considered safe low voltage

Answer (score 0):

That is a typical class AB amplifier. When the transistors were replaced *maybe they were not a matched pair* or the *CR15 temperature sensor is not close to them like it should be.*

Those outputs are wired as Darlington's to get the current gain. CR15 must physically touch or be mounted to the same heatsink as the output transistors, or they will overheat and burn up within minutes, short out and blow the fuse(s).

It is a push-pull amplifier with +/- 38 volt supply rails, so ground is the common return for input and speakers. The signal is symmetrical above and below the ground line. CR15 is a temperature sensor that regulates the bias current to the output transistors. The hotter they get, the less bias current CR15 will let them have.

Comment: Thanks again Sparky.  I will go over all of this.  What about the draining of filter capacitors to release charge even when guitar amp is not plugged in?  Is the cement type 2k ohm, 10 watt resistor fine for that, or is that only necessary for draining caps on tube amplifiers?

Comment: it's certainly not typical.

Comment: The biasing pair CR15's temperature dependency isn't as crucial as you paint it:  R45 reduces the bias voltage below AB level: at 1.15V per Darlington pair, this is definitely in the "off" region.

Comment: @Jack The floating power rail architecture loads the filter capacitors in a somewhat roundabout way.  the 2k resistors provide some base load that keeps them near the bridge rectifier output.  That's also important for keeping some basic relation between transformer center tap and the ground for ±15V since the ±15V are actually derived from the ±38V in spite of their grounds diverging by the output voltage.  It would be cleaner to have a separate transformer secondary for the ±15V.

Answer (score 0):

Short the input and check the DC voltages for biassing. (+/-1.15V). They should be very close. If they look good, play the thing for 10 minutes, recheck. If those voltages are high (eg +/-1.3V) the bias current is high and it could easily blow fuses or fry itself after a while.

By the way, this is why when an audio amp blows its output stage, just changing the transistors is often not enough. Very often something in the feedback network and/or biassing is out of whack, and it will fail again, immediately or after a while.

Answer (score -2):

Schematic is wrong. centre tap of TX should be ground, and junction R53 and R54 should connect to junction CR25, R60, and R63.
Junction of R53 and R54 is the Amplifier output.
In my opinion this is not a good design relying on diodes for biasing.

Comment: The schematic is right if that's the way they've built it. It seems to use a very unusual topology. The output transistors emitters are grounded through R53 and R54 while the DC supply is floating. The result is that the DC supply to the Q4 and Q6 collectors as well as the 0 V line will bounce around with the audio signal while the emitters stay close to GND.

Comment: The schematic is correct and the output stage works by pulling at the power rails of a separate floating end stage power supply, with the offset feeding the speaker.  I think that this topology may cause less strain on the output transistors for reactive load components (though not sure about that) and it keeps the whole output stage from traveling along with the output voltage, making for much better debugging of the driver stages with an oscilloscope since you get to see the controlling voltages offset to 0V rather than to the output rail (well, 0V _is_ the output rail).